# R turn each dataframe element into multiple n elements

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe (df) with yearly value for atmospheric deposition and a vector of 12 elements (mul).

```
str(df) 'data.frame':   220 obs. of  11 variables: 
$ year : num  1900 1902 1903 1904 1906 ...
$ BOX1 : num  0.72 0.72 0.72 0.72 0.72 ...  

mul <- c(0.7,0.7,1.3,1.7,0.7,1.0,0.7, 1.7,1.7,1.7,1.0,0.4)
```

I want to multiply each element of a given column 'BOX' for the 12 value of 'mul', so that a 220 elements column becomes a 2640 elements column. 
In the following example I've done it for the first element of column BOX1 but I  need to apply the procedure to all the elements at once.

`df$BOX1[1] * mul`

`[1] 0.503811 0.503811 0.935649 1.223541 0.503811 0.719730 0.503811 1.223541 1.223541 1.151568 0.719730 0.287892`

Thank you for your help

Comment: Not clear how you want your output to be, but I hope my solution helps.

Comment: It does exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# example data
df = data.frame(year = c(1900,1902,1903),
                BOX1 = c(0.72, 0.75, 0.80))

mul <- c(0.7,0.7,1.3,1.7,0.7,1.0,0.7, 1.7,1.7,1.7,1.0,0.4)

library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%                       # for each row
  mutate(x = list(BOX1 * mul)) %>%    # multiply value in BOX1 with mul and save results as a list
  unnest()                            # unnest data

# # A tibble: 36 x 3
#    year  BOX1     x
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  1900  0.72 0.504
# 2  1900  0.72 0.504
# 3  1900  0.72 0.936
# 4  1900  0.72 1.22 
# 5  1900  0.72 0.504
# 6  1900  0.72 0.72 
# 7  1900  0.72 0.504
# 8  1900  0.72 1.22 
# 9  1900  0.72 1.22 
# 10 1900  0.72 1.22 
# # ... with 26 more rows
```

You can remove column `BOX1` if you want.

You can also try to use a vectorized function instead of `rowwise`, which might be faster:

```
# vectorised function to multiply vectors
f = function(x,y) x*y
f = Vectorize(f)

df %>%
  mutate(x = list(f(BOX1, mul))) %>%    
  unnest()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with tidyverse :

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

mul %>% as.data.frame %>% rowid_to_column %>%  # to keep duplicates in 'mul'
   crossing(df) %>% mutate(v=BOX1*mul)         # when calling 'crossing'
```